# Navigate in Android Toolbar with keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, toolbar, accessibility

My app supports keyboard inputs for accessibility reasons. Users can switch between clickables or input fields by using tab via keyboard. However, I'm also trying to switch icons within android toolbar but with no luck by far.

Ideally, once user reaches the last item at the bottom, by clicking tab one more time, it should move to the first item in the app tool bar and move to the second item in the toolbar if tab is clicked one more time so on and so forth.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Have u got answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know, I am late to answer your question but this can help others. Refer this [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation)

`android:nextFocusForward` is the attr which consumes tab key event

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editText1"
    ... />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@id/button1"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/button1"
    ... />
<EditText
    android:id="@id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/button2"
    ...  />
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I was able to fix it by using the attributes on every view I was interested in on the layout:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:nextFocusDown="@id/yourDownViewId"
android:nextFocusLeft="@id/yourLeftViewId"
android:nextFocusRight="@id/yourRightViewId"
android:nextFocusUp="@id/yourUpViewId"
```

Also, for the full navigation to work I had to use `tab` and the `arrows keys`.
Let me know if this is helpful.

In my case, my views were in a vertical mode like a list and my `nextFocusRight` and `nextFocusDown` were the same bellow view and my `nextFocusLeft` and `nextFocusUp` the same above view.